# oracle cloud iam policy for tenancy a:b:c - can the root create policy in intermediary b?

Tags: oracle, amazon-iam, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have the following compartment structure:

- root tenancy
- compartment a under root
- nested b comp-t under a
- nested c compt- under b

if i write this policy:

```
Allow group admins to manage virtual-network-family 
in compartment a:b:c
```

does it mean the root still knows about comp-t b?

it can create vpc in intermediate compartment b?

Answer (score 2):

As per the Policy:

```
Allow group admins to manage virtual-network-family 
in compartment a:b:c
```

as you are specifying the path i.e. a:b:c , so that means this policy has to be attached to the parent compartment of "a" i.e. root here in this case.
Now answering to your query:

does it mean the root still knows about comp-t b? >>Yes it(Root) knows about compartment B, as you have specified the path from A -> C and B lies in between.

it can create vpc in intermediate compartment b? >>No, the policy is defined for the permission to create resources in C compartment. But as the policy is being attached to the root compartment so the administrator of the root compartment can modify the policy.

You can refer this document for more details [Policies and Compartment Hierarchies](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Concepts/policies.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In your case your policy is specific to compartment "C". i.e. admins can create VCNs in compartment C only, not in root or A or B, provided you have not added another policy that says `allow group admins to manage all-resources IN TENANCY`. I guess using "admins" in your example is not a good example.

Also what do you mean by "